# Get a list of files in a folder and list them in an e-mail body

Tags: c#, email

I'm new to C# and am trying to get a list of files from a directory and then send them in an e-mail. I can do both things individually, but just can't seem to work out. Here is my basic code to get a list of files:

```
foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
Message.Print(str);
}
```

For my e-mail code, I have this:

```
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(server, Port);
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = ssl;
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(sender);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "Test e-mail";
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;
        message.Body = "List directory content here";
        message.To.Add(reciever);
        smtpClient.Send(message);
```

No matter what I try, I just can't seem to work out how to list the directory contents in the e-mail body. Can anyone assist?

Comment: foreach (file str in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
message.Body += str
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles(path)` is an array, you can use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an string out of that instead of your current `foreach` loop, then you just use the resulting string for `message.Body`.

```
message.Body = sting.Join(",", Directory.GetFiles(path))
```

This is the initial step to get it working, validations need to be done in order to make this production ready. Check [Directory.GetFiles exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) to get an idea of all the stuff that can go wrong with this code.